# Animation duration not behaving properly in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, animation, safari, css-animations

We're working on a simple project, where we're using CSS animation.
We're trying to change the animation duration with JavaScript. 
Changing the animation duration works in every browser except safari and iOS.

We're using this code to change the animation duration.

```
document.getElementById("circle").style.animationDuration = data.pulse+"ms"
document.getElementById("circle").style.webkitAnimationDuration = data.pulse+"ms"
```

And this is the css:

```css
@keyframes pulse {       
            0% {transform: scale(0); opacity: 0;}
            30% {opacity: 1;}   
            100% {opacity: 0; transform: scale(0.8);}
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes pulse {       
            0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0); opacity: 0;}
            30% {opacity: 1;}   
            100% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);}
        }

        @-moz-keyframes pulse {       
            0% {-moz-transform: scale(0); opacity: 0;}
            30% {opacity: 1;}
            100% {opacity: 0; -moz-transform: scale(0.8);}
        }
```

On safari it runs one time, after that the object stays stationary in it's original proportion.

We tried several different ways of defining the `webkitAnimationDuration;` for instance like `["-webkit-animation-duration"]`

Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using any `-webkit-keyframes` in your css codes? If so, could you also please include it?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem too and solved it by forcing Safari to re-render the element after changing the animation-duration.

```
var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
circle.style.animationDuration = data.pulse+"ms";
circle.style.display = "none";
setTimeout(() => circle.style.display = "block", 0);
```

By briefly hiding, then displaying the element, Safari will render it with the new animation duration.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Safari:

```
document.getElementById("circle").style.WebkitAnimationDuration = data.pulse+"ms"
// Code for Chrome, Safari, and Opera
```

Comment: Hey Hari Om! This helped a lot, initially!

It actually takes over the proper tempo right now but it refuses to do so when we ping it with new data. 
Which is strange, because it does work on every other browser!